# How to get transfer function of multi input-multi output system using system Matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here I've matrices of multi input-multi output system (**matrix D is not zero**) and I want to take **transfer function** of this model.
    size  A [9*9]

```
A = [-6.932e-2,17.41,-36.75,0,0,0,-6.0660,-31.54,0;
    -1.435e-4,2.719e-2,-1.411e-3,3.467e-1,0,-9.380e-1,7.139e-2,-1.691e-2,0;
    -4.537e-4,1.870e-3,-2.025e-1,0,1,0,-4.688e-2,7.563e-3,0;
    -1.304e-4,-7.179,-4.916e-1,-6.172e-1,-3.689e-2,7.631e-1,0,0,0;
    2.297e-5,0,-8.667e-1,4.393e-2,-1.947e-1,-2.026e-2,0,0,0;
    1.964e-5,4.263e-2,-1.329e-2,1.233e-3,1.579e-2,-1.600e-1,0,0,0;
    0,0,0,1,1.941e-1,2.771e-1,0,6.258e-2,0;
    0,0,0,0,8.192e-1,-5.736e-1,-5.612e-2,0,0;
    0,0,0,0,6.055e-1,8.648e-1,0,2.006e-2,0]

size  B = [9*4]

B = [0,0,-7.560,9.067e-4;
     -6.952e-3,1.293e-2,0,0;
     0,0,-3.425e-2,-9.577e-7;
     4.249,5.989e-1,0,0;
     0,0,-1.796,0;
     -7.287e-2,-2.877e-1,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0]

size  C = [7*9]

C = [0,-5.758e-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0;
     0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0;
     0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0;
     0,2.719e-2,-1.411e-3,3.467e-1,0,-9.380e-1,7.139e-2,0,0]

size D = [7*4]

D = [-1.298e-1,-1.610e-1,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     -6.952e-3,1.293e-2,0,0]
```

How Can I get Transfer function of this model using Matlab?

Comment: I'm not that good at signals. If I recall, a transfer function, `H`, is defined as output over input, `Y/X`. Is there enough information here?

Comment: No,Because D is nonzero I cant use "ss" command of Matlab.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is this is just numbers - we don't know what the model really is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a state space model from the system matrices using the [`ss`](http://mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ss.html) command. It doesn't matter that `D` is non-zero, as MATLAB uses the standard form when creating a model with `ss`:

[image: model] (Image from [Wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation#/media/File:Typical_State_Space_model.png))

[image: equations]

So you create the model with

```
sys = ss(A,B,C,D);
```

and read out the transfer function:

```
tf(sys)
```

which returns a `7x4 tf` object containing the transfer function from every input to every output.

*Note:* The matrix `A` you posted here is not correct: there are too many zeros in some lines, but I assume that is a simple copy-paste mistake. After removing them, this works fine.

Comment: Dear @hbaderts I've got matrix A using model linearization.Why it might be incorrect?

Comment: @lahidj try copying the `A` posted above to MATLAB - there will be an error. But I guess you have the correct `A`  inside your MATLAB session, and there was a mistake while copying it to stackoverflow.

Comment: A matrix added to post

Comment: Please try to add matrices as MATLAB-code which can easily be copied to MATLAB. I edited the corrected matrix back into your question. Does the answer then solve your problem?